# What's the best approach for user auth login?

Tags: javascript, angular

**AuthService**

```
login(user: User){
    return this.http.post<any>(`${this.API_URL}`, {
        email: user.username,
        password: user.password
    });
}

isUserLoggedIn(){
    return this.http.get<any>(`${this.API_URL}/1`);
}

logoff(){
    //this.loggedIn.next(null);
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
}
```

**LoginComponent**

```
onSubmit(){
    this.submitted = true;
    this.authService.login(this.loginForm.value).subscribe(r => {
        if(r.success){
            this.router.navigate(['/home']);
        }
    });
}
```

**Auth Guard**

```
canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
): any{
    return this.authService.isUserLoggedIn()
    .pipe(
        map(res => {
            if (res.isAuth){
                return true;
            }
            this.router.navigate(['/login']); 
            return false;
        })
    );
}
```

- `LoginComponent`: sends the data to an `API` for login (`username` and `password`). The `API` will return `success = true` if the user exists on the database;
- `Guard`: (`isUserLoggedIn()`) check if user is logged in
  and if the `session` is still alive.

Is there a better approach for user `authentication` in the Angular 4+?
Is this approach used in most projects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe, you could store user's data in local storage when he logins the first time. Then use a `BehaviorSubject` from rxjs and convert it to Observable. So every time the user has any changes (language, first name, etc), in any parts of your app you can access to that information.

So a thing like that:

#### Login Component

```js
this.userService.login(username, password).subscribe(s => {
  this.userService.user = s;
  this.router.navigate(['/home'])
})
```

#### User Service

```js
private userSubject: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
readonly currentUser$: Observable<any> = this.userSubject.asObservable();

set user(user: any) {
  // manipulate your user info and put it in localStorage after
  this.userSubject.next(user);
}

get user() {
  return this.userSubject.value ? this.userSubject.value : window.localStorage.getItem('user');
}
```

#### Auth Guard

Now in your guard, you can check the current user from the get method or you can subscribe to user observable, it's your choice

```js
canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
): any{
    return this.userServivce.user ? true : false;
}
```

You can complicate your logic as you wish.